Why can't my Python interpreter or Arlpy see the Acoustics Toolbox models?
I am trying to use the Acoustics Toolbox in Python, using the arlpy module. I am able to import arlpy but it cannot see any of the models:
>>> import arlpy.uwapm as pm
>>> print(pm.models())
[]
>>>

I have installed the Acoustics Toolbox files onto my local drive, and have set up the Environment path appropriately.
The models are located in
C:\WorkTools\AcousticToolbox\atWin10_2020_11_4\windows-bin-20201102\
and I have added that path to the list of environment paths for both System and User.
I'm aware of this answer and this one. They do describe what I'm supposed to do, but do not address what to do when it doesn't work.
I'm using Python 3.12.4. I get the same issue whether I try to use the models from Spyder or from the command prompt.

If you take a look at the code:
_models = []

...

def models(env=None, task=None):
    """List available models.

    :param env: environment to model
    :param task: arrivals/eigenrays/rays/coherent/incoherent/semicoherent
    :returns: list of models that can be used

    >>> import arlpy.uwapm as pm
    >>> pm.models()
    ['bellhop']
    >>> env = pm.create_env2d()
    >>> pm.models(env, task=coherent)
    ['bellhop']
    """
    if env is not None:
        env = check_env2d(env)
    if (env is None and task is not None) or (env is not None and task is None):
        raise ValueError('env and task should be both specified together')
    rv = []
    for m in _models:
        if m[1]().supports(env, task):
            rv.append(m[0])
    return rv

and you called:
pm.models()

without passing an env. With for m in [] the loop isn't even entered and rv ([]) is returned. I think
"""
...
>>> pm.models()
['bellhop']
...
"""

in the docstring is erroneous.

It is not erroneous. My colleague is able to reproduce the expected behaviour of pm.models() returning ['bellhop'], and in the past I have been able to. There is also lots of start-up guides online which demonstrate this. The problem I have is that I can't reproduce this for whatever reason, meaning that I cannot run any of the acoustic models used by the toolbox.
